# How to make if/else statement in Django Html Template?

Tags: django, templates, browser

I want to test for the user's browser. If Internet Explorer, then this paragraph. else this paragraph.

How do I do that in a django html template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it using Django. Use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html). Example:

```
<!--[if IE]>
According to the conditional comment this is Internet Explorer<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 5]>
According to the conditional comment this is Internet Explorer 5 and up<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 6]>
According to the conditional comment this is Internet Explorer greater than 6<br />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Django templates are rendered on the server side, what actually goes to the browser is the output is the rendered template. So you can't write browser specific code in the template, *unless* you capture that information from the request, pass it as a variable to the template, when you render it, which then uses that value to produce browser specific code.

Comment: Rm is clearly right, but you could inject javascript.  I think the `navigator` object contains everything about the browser, and you could create a condition in javsacript that displays one paragraph if ie, else disply another paragraph

Answer (score 0):

Don't. There should almost never be a need for this. If you really really think you need it, use IE's conditional comments.